# Challenging probability problem

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, power-series, roots

Hy, I hope everyone is doing fine. Lately I have been studying the topic of probability, I am aiming to improve on it, recently i came across this hard problem.

Let $(u_{n})$ a sequence of random independent variables identically distributed following Rademacher distribution. And let  $f(x)=\sum_{n \geq 0} u_{n} x^{n}$.

Prove that : $$ f(x)~~\text{almost surely has infinitely many zeros  in}~~ [0,1].$$

I have been stuck on it for weeks now, but I did find out a hint to solve it on a forum by searching about it, Here is the hint: 
Construct an increasing sequence $(x_{k})$ such that the event $A_{k}=\{f(x_{0}),...,f(x_{k}) \text{are not zero and have the same sign} \}$ are such that $p(A_{k+1})\leq \frac{6}{7} p(A_{k})$.

I find it difficult to construct by induction such sequence in a way that may permit us to solve the problem. Any proposition is welcome.

Comment: I think the point is to get 0's by looking for sign changes (and appealing to intermediate value theorem)

Comment: @mathworker21 yes that's exactly my idea, If I am able to construct such $A_{k}$ in a good way  the event $\cap A_{k}$  will have a probability equal to $0$ wich ensure the existence of a 0's in $[x_{0},1]$ and we apply the same raisonning on $[0,x_{0}]$  and so on ....

Comment: A more general setting: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/266832/sign-oscillations-for-power-series-with-random-coefficients

Comment: @leonbloy thank you a  lot for your help and interest, the article is very advanced for me.

Comment: @uvw what's wrong with Robert Israel's answer? looks perfect to me

Comment: @mathworker21 If you have found a mistake in the answer by DLeMeur, you can point this out in the comments and downvote the answer if necessary. Please do not, however, edit the post without valid explanation or alternative.

Comment: @mathworker21 can you give more details about the construction ? I don't see how  he construct $t_{n}$ and ensure that the probability is $ > 1- \frac{1}{n^{2}}$ , I understand the finish of the proof, indeed we can use Borel Cantelli lemma. But the construction I don't understand it.

Comment: @uvw yea, one needs to work it out. ill try when i have time

Comment: @mathworker21 One should somehow use that the series is uniformly convergent over any disk $\{z:|z|\leq r\}$, where $r<1$. That's, somehow the sign of $f(x)$, where $x<1$ is fixed, essentially depends only on first $N$ terms of the series, where $N$ depends on $x$.

Comment: @jvdhooft there is valid explanation: see joriki's comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3655915/random-power-series-and-zeros)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $t_n = 1-\frac{1}{3^{3^{2n}}}$ and $K_n = 3^{3^{2n-1}}$ for $n \ge 1$. We claim that, for all $n$ large (maybe $n \ge 10$ is fine), with probability at least $1-\frac{1}{n^2}$, the sign of $\sum_{k \ge 1} u_kt_n^k$ is the same as the sign as $\sum_{K_n \le k < K_{n+1}} u_kt_n^k$. Note that $|\sum_{k \ge K_{n+1}} u_k t_n^k| \le \sum_{k \ge K_{n+1}} t_n^k \le \frac{t_n^{K_{n+1}}}{1-t_n} = (1-\frac{1}{3^{3^{2n}}})^{3^{3^{2n+1}}}3^{3^{2n}} \approx e^{-3^{3^{2n+1}}/3^{3^{2n}}}3^{3^{2n}} = e^{-3^{3^{2n}}}3^{3^{2n}} \approx e^{-3^{3^{2n}}}$. And, $|\sum_{k < K_n} u_kt_n^k| \le K_n = 3^{3^{2n-1}}$. Therefore, if $|\sum_{K_n \le k < K_{n+1}} u_kt_n^k| \ge 2\cdot 3^{3^{2n-1}}$ (say), then $\sum_{k \ge 1} u_k t_n^k$ has the same sign as $\sum_{K_n \le k < K_{n+1}} u_k t_n^k$. And with probability at least $1-\frac{1}{n^2}$, we'll have $|\sum_{K_n \le k < K_{n+1}} u_kt_n^k| \ge 2\cdot 3^{3^{2n-1}}$. Indeed, $\mathbb{E}\left[|\sum_{K_n \le k < K_{n+1}} u_k t_n^k|^2\right] = \sum_{K_n \le k < K_{n+1}} t_n^{2k} \ge 3^{3^{2n}}$, and we have concentration since everything is i.i.d.. So by Borel-Cantelli, with probability $1$, for all but finitely many $n$ we will have that $\sum_{K_n \le k < K_{n+1}} u_kt_n^k$ has the same sign as $\sum_{k \ge 1} u_kt_n^k$; clearly the signs of $\sum_{K_n \le k < K_{n+1}} u_kt_n^k$ are independent as $n$ ranges and each half $50-50$ probability of being positive or negative, so with probability $1$ we get infinitely many sign changes and thus infinitely many roots.

Comment: Here is how I would have preferred to write this answer. $\sum_{k ge K_{n+1}} u_kt_n^k$ is exponentially small, so we can ignore it, and so $\sum_{K_n \le k < K_{n+1}} u_k t_n^k$ is where nearly all of the sum is, since $t_n^k$ is roughly constant for $2^{2^{2n}}$ terms and there are very few terms $k < 2^{2^{2n-1}}$. And by basic probability (a random walk after n steps is very likely to be at least $\sqrt{n}$ far out), $\sum_{K_n \le k < K_{n+1}} u_kt_n^k$ will be large enough in magnitude to not be affected by $k < K_n$ or $k \ge K_{n+1}$.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I understand the idea and the proof just one thing I don't see directly is why the fact that $\mathbb{E}\left[|\sum_{K_n \le k < K_{n+1}} u_k t_n^k|^2\right] = \sum_{K_n \le k < K_{n+1}} t_n^{2k} \ge 2^{2^{2n}}$ is enough to ensure that the probability of having $|\sum_{K_n \le k < K_{n+1}} u_k t_n^k| \geq 2  \times 2^{2^{2n-1}} $ is at least $1- \frac{1}{n^{2}}$ ?

Comment: @uvw ahh, actually the numerology is off a bit, since the square root of $2^{2^{2n}}$ is $2^{2^{2n-1}}$, which is less than $2^{2^{2n-1}}$. so I'll have to change some of the $2$s to $3$s. Who knew that $2^{2^{2n}}$ would not be large enough!

Comment: @uvw ok fixed, but you're still probably asking why at least $1-\frac{1}{n^2}$. So $1-\frac{1}{n^2}$ is pretty arbitrary; the probability will be much closer to $1$; the reason is that the random variable $|\sum_{K_n \le k < K_{n+1}} u_kt_n^k|^2$ is a sum of many, many independent things, so it concentrates very closely to its mean. So the probability that $|\sum_{K_n \le k < K_{n+1}} u_kt_n^k|^2 \ge \frac{1}{2}3^{3^{2n}}$ is insanely large and thus the probability that $|\sum_{K_n \le k < K_{n+1}} u_kt_n^k| \ge 3^{3^{2n-1}}$ is insanely large.

Comment: @uvw  See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality#General_case_of_bounded_random_variables).

Comment: everything is clear now,  I didn't know about Hoeffding inequality, I learned a lot from this discussion with you thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution without using the advice you mentionned.

You can write :  $f(x)=\sum_{n \geq 0} u_{n} x^{n} = f_n(x) + R_n(x)$, where $f_n(x) = 
\sum_{k=0}^n u_n x^n$ and $R_n(x) = \sum_{k\geq n+1} u_n x^n$. 
Intuitively, what happens is quite clear : the graph of $f$ should oscillate up and down, somewhat like a random walk, when approaching the line of equation $x=1$. The problem is to show it rigorously.

With this intuition in mind, a nice idea is to define an increasing sequence $x_n$ such that $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n = 1$ and $f(x_n)$ is near to $f_n(1) = \sum_{k=0}^n u_k$. I will denote $s_n = \sum_{k=0}^n u_k$, the random walk.

Let us compare : 
$f(x) - f_n(1) = R_n(x) + (f_n(x) - f_n(1))$

Let us see what happens if we make easy majorations.

It is easy to show that $|R_n(x)| \leq \frac{x^{n+1}}{1-x}$.

On the other hand, $|f_n(x) - f_n(1)| \leq \sum_{k=0}^n (1 - x^k) \leq (\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{s=0}^{k-1} x^s) (1-x) \leq \frac{n(n+1)}{2} (1-x)$.

We would like to build $x_n$ such that the two following quantities are small : 
$\frac{n(n+1)}{2} (1-x_n)$ and $\frac{x_n^{n+1}}{1-x_n}$
Let us try $x_n = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$.
The first quantity is equivalent to $\frac{n}{2}$. The second is equivalent to $\frac{e^{-2}}{2}n $. So $|f(x) - s_n| \leq \frac{1 + e^{-2} + \epsilon}{2} n$ for $n$ big enough. Unfortunately, it is too big, but we are quite close. We need a majoration weaker than $\beta \sqrt n$ where $0 < \beta < 1$, because $\frac{s_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ has almost surely lim sup equal 1 and lim inf equal -1.

It is possible to have sharper majorations be using Abel lemma. I will make it quite fast, I encourage you to make the calculations yourself to check. The philosophy is the following : $|s_n|$ can be trivially majorated by $n$, but we can for $\epsilon>0$ majorate it almost surely by $C(u,\epsilon) + (1+\epsilon)\sqrt{n}$ where $C(u, \epsilon)>0$ is a constant depending only on $u$ and $\epsilon$ (not on $x$ or on $n$).. This enables to win a $\sqrt{n}$ in both majorations.

We have : 
$ R_n(x)= -\sum_{k\geq n+1} (\sum_{s=n+1}^k u_s) (x^{k+1} - x^k) $. Let $\epsilon>0$ . Then, you can check that almost surely, 
$|R_n(x)| \leq  C(u, \epsilon)(1-x) + (1+\epsilon)\sum_{k \geq n+1} \sqrt{k-n} (x^k - x^{k+1})$
Where $C(u, \epsilon)>0$ is a constant depending only on $u$ and $\epsilon$ (not on $x$ or on $n$).
The majorant of $|R_n(x)|$ should behave like this when $x\rightarrow 1$ : $\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{1-x}}$ (there is probably a multiplicative constant missing).

For $|f_n(x) - f_n(1)|$, using the same trick, I think you can get $n\sqrt{n}$ for the majoration of the second term (multiplicative constant missing).

So you take again $x_n = 1-\frac{1}{n}$ as before and you win a $\sqrt{n}$ in both terms, so it should be just sufficent to conclude ! ... Quite magical isn't it ?

Comment: please how do you prove that almost surely $|s_{n}| \leq C(u,\varepsilon)+(1+\varepsilon ) \sqrt{n}$ ?    @DLeMeur