# Random power series and zeros

Tags: real-analysis, probability, random-variables, power-series, roots

Hy, I hope everyone is doing well. I just recalled a problem that have been bothering me. I have already posted it here [Challenging probability problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3205113/challenging-probability-problem) but it seems that I still can not figure out how to complete the solution formalized by DLeMeur, he used the fact that $\frac{s_{n}}{\sqrt{n}}$ has limit sup $1$ and limit inf $-1$, which is incorrect actually it is $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ so the argument seems to fail.

Is it possible to obtain the estimate $|s_{n}| \leq C(u, \varepsilon) + (1+\varepsilon) \sqrt{n}$ by an other way ?
If we manage to do so DLeMeur's idea can still work to solve the problem.

Edit: As pointed out this estimate is false, Any idea to solve the problem ?

Comment: The [law of the iterated logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm) states that

$$
 \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{\pm s_n}{\sqrt{2n \log\log n}} = 1 \quad \text{a.s.}\;,
$$

which seems to contradict this estimate.

Comment: Thank you for the reference so the proof given in the above link can not be fixed.

Comment: @uvw what? so his answer in the question you linked to is false but you have it accepted? why didn't you unaccept his answer and put a bounty on that question?

Comment: @mathworker21 done, sorry I am not used to math stack exchange system, I accepted his answer as a thanks for the help, and thought that maybe I could fix the idea...